# Capture a live video of handwriting using pen and paper and replace the hand in video with some object or cursor

Tags: video-capture, p5.js, ml5.js

I want to process the captured video. I will try to capture the video of handwriting on paper / drawing on paper. But I do not want to show the hand or pen on the paper while live streaming via p5.js.
Can this be done using machine learning?
Any idea how to implement this?

Comment: I dont get the concept.. You want to use your phone aimed at paper and transmit this via network somehow. What about situations like covering large part of the paper with hand? How would you compensate for that? But I guess you could put a lot of effort and implement super inteligent OpenCV solution https://opencv.org/android/

Comment: @nayana Im using p5.js to live stream the video. but not able to implement replacing the hand in the video with some cursor icon or so..

Comment: I think this question is too broad with very little input from your side.. but who knows maybe somebody will take time to answer in detail (since you added a bounty).. I suggest to create another question with details regarding your problems with p5.js solution with reproducible examples.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right you want to detect where in the image the hand is a draw an overlay on this position right?

If so You can use YOLO [more information](https://towardsdatascience.com/yolo-you-only-look-once-real-time-object-detection-explained-492dc9230006) to detect where the hand is.

There are some trained networks that you can download maybe they are good enough, maybe you have to train your own just for handy.

There are also some libery for yolo and JS https://github.com/ModelDepot/tfjs-yolo-tiny

Answer (score 0):

You may not need to go the full ML object segmentation route.

If the paper's position and illumination are constant (or at least knowable) you could try some simple heuristic comparing the pixels in the current frame with a short history and using the most constant pixel values. There might be some lag as new parts of your drawing 'become constant' so maybe you could try some modification to the accumulation, such as if the pixel was white and is going black.